# Why dropdown is not setting default value for undefined value of ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to set the default value for the dropdown to be set to 1 (now it's not defined. 
I tried the below code, But it's not working.

I tried to print the value of `item.n_fold`, it shows blank in the page.
I want to set it to 1 for empty, null or undefined value.

```
<div flex=5> <md-input-container>
{{item.n_fold}}
<input type="number" step="1" min="1" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? '': event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" id="train_n_file" ng-init="item.n_fold = item.n_fold || '1'" ng-model="item.n_fold" ng-disabled="item.train_select=='training_time_range'" style="margin-top: -2px;" class="input-div" value="{{1}}"> </md-input-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake you have written:

g-init= instead of **ng-init=**

so your code for initiation of the dropdown should be as follows

```
<div flex=5> <md-input-container>
    {{item.n_fold}}
    <input type="number" step="1" min="1" 
        onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? '': event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" 
    id="train_n_file" 
    ng-init="item.n_fold= (item.n_fold || '1')" 
    ng-model="item.n_fold" 
    ng-disabled="item.train_select=='training_time_range'" 
    style="margin-top: -2px;" class="input-div" value="{{1}}"> 
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using ng-init only, it was copied here by mistake. Please check your code. Question edited